# $PWD variable equivalent of pwd -P

Tags: shell-script, symlink

I want to use the `$PWD` variable in a script, but I want it to be the hardware path without symlinks. I know about `/bin/pwd` and `pwd -P`, but those aren't variables.

I know that I can use:

```
setenv MYPWD `pwd -P`
```

But I remember there being another way to do it.

Comment: some shells support `$(pwd -P)` syntax, as opposed to back ticks, but I don't think (t)csh is one (or two) of them. Also, for why you shouldn't script in (t)csh, see: http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/anti/csh/

Answer (score 5):

In POSIX shells, after

```
cd -P .
```

`$PWD` will contain a symlink-free path.

In `zsh`, `$PWD:A` will expand to the symlink-free version of `$PWD` (works for any variable, not just `$PWD`).

In `zsh`, `setopt chase_links`, and in `tcsh`, `set symlinks = chase`, cause `cd` to make sure `$PWD` is symlink-free. However, that only works after the first `cd`. In `zsh`, `cd .` will make `$PWD` symlink free, but not in `tcsh` where you'd need `cd "$cwd"` (which is not guaranteed to work).

Comment: I'd rather not have to change the directory, I thought that there was a variable for this already.

Comment: @BrianPostow - not that I've ever seen. There is $CWD, but it suffers the same issue.

Comment: @BrianPostow, `cd .`, by definition, doesn't change the directory.

Comment: cd -P appears to, even though you are in the same physical dir, the logical path changes. You can use pushd and popd to counter this.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no such variable provided by the environment that will guarantee that its value is the physical path and not a linked version.

Given this your options are limited to the choices that you've already mentioned plus the following alternative.

#### readlink

You can use the command `readlink` to get the physical directory/file that a symbolic link is pointing to:

#### Example

*sample data:*

```
$ ln -s /usr/bin/ack ack

$ ls -l |grep ack
lrwxrwxrwx   1 saml saml        12 Aug 15 11:48 ack -> /usr/bin/ack
```

*physical location:*

```
$ readlink ./ack
/usr/bin/ack
$ readlink /home/saml/ack 
/usr/bin/ack
$ readlink $HOME/ack
/usr/bin/ack
```

If the value you pass to `readlink` isn't a link it won't return anything. You can force it to return the canonical value by using the `-f` switch:

```
$ echo $PWD
/home/saml

$ readlink -f $PWD
/home/saml
```

#### References

- [readlink man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink)

Comment: A command doesn't help any. If I wanted a command I could just use /bin/pwd or pwd -P. I want a variable.

Comment: No variable exists in the way that you want it. See @StephaneChazelas answer too. He'll tell you the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ksh93`, there is a simple way to implement that variable. Just add this discipline function either at the beginning of your script or being sourced by it:

```
function PWDP.get
{
  .sh.value=$(pwd -P)
}
```

Then, you can just use the PWDP variable as you expect:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ ln -s /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
$ cd /tmp/bar
$ echo $PWD
/tmp/bar
$ echo $PWDP
/tmp/foo
```

**Edit**, a "slightly" more complex solution trying to handle Stéphane Chazelas point:

```
function PWDP.get
{
    typeset p=$(pwd -P; echo .)
    .sh.value=${p%??}
}
```

Comment: as a small note: that doesn't work if the (physical) current directory ends in newline characters.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Answer updated with something to avoid this point but I have no doubt you'll find more issues with it ...

Comment: Ouch. Yes, I've updated with a simpler and more reliable alternative. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Much simpler indeed, thanks !